# "at line" vs "in line"

Tags: differences, prepositions, at-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which preposition in front of “line” — “on”, “in”, “at”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65312/which-preposition-in-front-of-line-on-in-at)

Given a numbered list of lines of text (in my case an algorithm), should I use "in line" or "at line" to refer to the content of the line?

For example

> the code at lines 5-10 loops over the elements of a list

or

> the operation in line 10 sums two positive integers.

Comment: Related: [Which preposition in front of “line” — “on”, “in”, “at”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65312/which-preposition-in-front-of-line-on-in-at)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think there are three usages here.

One can talk about a line of code as one entity, for example the "code at line ten".

One can talk about a fragment of code that spans many lines, for example "the code at (or between, or from .. to ..) lines 5-10".

Finally, one can talk about a fragment of code within a line, for example "the object instantiation with a null constructor, which is found in line ten".

Answer (score 6):

If referring to a specific line, then "at" would indicate either a statement about the entire line, or possibly about the first element, while "in" would be about a subset of the line.